# Update multiple rows at one time with Odoo Xmlrpc

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-12

I want to update multiple records of "sale.order.line" products, using Odoo Xmlrpc

```
for (let i = 0; i <sell.products.length; i ++) {                
          var inParams = [];
          inParams.push ([value1 [i]]);  //id to update
          inParams.push ({
            'name': sale.products [i] .name,
            'product_uom_qty': sales.products [i] .product_uom_qty,
            'price_unit': sales.products [i] .price_unit,
            'product_id': sales.products [i] .product_id
          });
          var params = [];
          params.push (inParams);
          db.execute_kw ('sale.order.line', 'write', params, function (err, value) {
            if (err) {
              return console.log (err);
            }
            return console.log ('Result2:', value);
          });
        }
```

and here is the error: 
raise psycopg2.OperationalError (msg) \ npsycopg2.OperationalError: Unable to use a closed cursor.

I use Odoo version 12
thank you in advance

Comment: Hello Daya, Need more context to help you.

Comment: Hello @jo541 , thank you for your answer

I do stock management with angular as front-end, expressjs as back-end and odoo as database.
to link Odoo and expressJs; I use Odoo-xmlrpc

In the case of modification of a delivery note in the sales module:
I want to recover all products and then edit them in Odoo
the problem i can not change them all at the same time.

Comment: The write method of Odoo could change mutli record only with same value.
Exemple([1, 2, 3, 4],{'foo':'foo'}).

Answer (score 1):

thank you jo541

i found the solution by changing odoo xmlrpc by [odoo](Https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo) And it works very well, here is the code:

```
`for (let i = 0; i <sale.products.length; i ++) {
     var params = {
               'name': 'Product #' + sale.products[i].product_id,
               'product_uom_qty': sale.products[i].product_uom_qty,
               'price_unit': sale.products[i].price_unit,
               'product_id': sale.products[i].product_id
     }
     odoo2.update ("sale.order.line", sale.products [i].id, params, function (err, value) {
               if (err) {
                 return console.log (err);
               }
               console.log (value);

    

     });
    };`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've hit a similar problem and the cause was that my Odoo server wasn't able to handle concurrent connections.

I've solved the problem by using a mutex/lock to limit concurrent access to the API, and now everything works well :-)

Here's some code for convenience :

```js
import * as Odoo from "odoo-xmlrpc";
import AwaitLock from 'await-lock';

var odoo = new Odoo({
    url: "odooserver/xmlrpc/2",
    db: "databasename",
    username: "username",
    password: "password"
});

var lock = new AwaitLock();

const callOdoo = async (model, method, params) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    odoo.connect(async (err) => {
      if (err) reject(new Error(err));
      await lock.acquireAsync();
      odoo.execute_kw(model, method, params, (err, value) => {
        lock.release();
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error(err));
        }
        console.log(value);
        resolve(value);
      });
    });
  });
}

async function getStockFromOdoo() {
  let items = await callOdoo(
    'product.product',
    'search_read',
    [
      [[['x_volume', '>=', '0.1']]],
      {'fields': ['x_beername', 'qty_available', 'x_volume', 'name', 'default_code']}
    ]
  );
  // Do something with items here.
}

async function getCustomers() {
  let items = await callOdoo(
    'res.partner',
    'search_read',
    [
      [[['is_company', '=', true],['customer', '=', true]]],
      {'fields': ['name']}
    ]);
  // Do something with items here
}

async function createSaleOrder(order){
  let orderId = await callOdoo(
    'sale.order',
    'create',
    [[{ partner_id: order.customer.id }]]
  );
  order.orders.forEach(async (line) => {
    await callOdoo(
      'sale.order.line',
      'create',
      [[{'order_id': orderId, 'product_id': line.beer.id, 'product_uom_qty': line.quantity}]]);
  });
  // do something with it here.
}
```